# ArgumentException on method invocation with reflection: Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'T[]'

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to call a method with reflection. This is the class:

```
public class MyData<T> where T : struct
{
    public void CopyFrom(T[] array)
    { /* code */ }
}
```

Now I have an array that contains the objects that I want to put into the class, but my objects are boxed.

```
var container = new MyData<int>();
var method = typeof(MyData<>).GetMethod("CopyFrom");
object[] boxed = new object[] {1, 2, 3};
method.Invoke(container, new object[] { boxed });
```

The error that I get is this:
`System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'T[]'.`

What is the right way to call this method?

Note that this is not a generic method. So it's not duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: Asking the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689029/argumentexception-on-method-invocation-object-of-type-system-object-cannot) is not the right way to do this.  You're better off editing your original question so that it's viable to be reopened.

Comment: @Zer0 Quickly closing questions before reading them is not right too. Also my question didn't need any editing. It shouldn't have been closed in the first place.

Comment: I don't disagree.  I have voted to reopen questions.  But I also don't think it's good practice to simply re-post a question because it's closed.  Maybe someone with better knowledge can tell you exactly what steps you should take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following

```
public void InvokeCopyFrom(Type genericType,object[] parameters)
{
    //Create BoundedGenericType
    var openGeneric = typeof(MyData<>);
    var boundGenericType = openGeneric.MakeGenericType(genericType);

    // Create instance based on bounded type
    var container = Activator.CreateInstance(boundGenericType);

    // Get MethodInfo from Bounded Type
    var method = boundGenericType.GetMethod("CopyFrom");

    // Cast the boxed parameter collection
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);
    var arrayOfDestinationType = this.GetType()
                             .GetMethod("CastAsArray")
                             .MakeGenericMethod(listType.GetGenericArguments().First())
                             .Invoke(this, new[] {parameters});
    // Invoke the method
    method.Invoke(container,new object[]{arrayOfDestinationType});
}
```

Where CastAsArray is defined as

```
public T[] CastAsArray<T>(object[] source)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
       result.Add((T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T)));
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I don't know the type 'int' in compile time. So I cannot do `Cast<int>()`. The only thing that I have is the `System.Type` that corresponds to type (i.e: typeof(int)). Is it possible to do casting given an instance of `System.Type`?

Comment: I also called `Cast<>()` and `ToArray()` methods with reflection and it worked. I'm marking this as answer but it would be nice if you added these too for future searches.

Comment: `var container = new MyData<int>();` depends on type `int` here... so the improved version of this code with `Cast<>` and `ToArray()` will work as long  as it is `MyClass<int>`. If you change this to `MyClass<float>` it will not work with array of object with `int` values in it. And if you know the type of values in object then you don't need to reflection on it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Please check the updated answer

Comment: @AnuViswan You nailed it right there... properly fitting answer... Upvoted.